# 'global' undefined after running webpack

Tags: webpack

I have a very simple wrapper module around a global object set by the environment the scripts are run. The wrapper module simply does:

```
module.exports = global.foobar;
```

Previously when I used browserify this worked fine. When in the browser, `global` was the same as `window`.

However, I'm switching to webpack and after running webpack the meaning of `global` has changed. In the browser it's no longer an alias to `window`, instead it's `undefined`, and I get `cannot read property foobar of undefined`.

Now, in the case of my wrapper module I can fix that in other ways, but I have other dependencies, and further down the chain the `buffer` package is used. That package also uses `global` ([see here](https://github.com/feross/buffer/blob/master/index.js#L46)) and also crashes after I've run webpack:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'TYPED_ARRAY_SUPPORT' of undefined
```

Is there some way I can make webpack treat `global` the same way browserify did, with `global` being an alias of `window`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally found the problem. I have two webpack builds: the first one building my library and the second building the demo. The problem was that both configs had:

```
{
  node: {
    global: true
  }
}
```

It works fine if the first one (the one building the lib) has `global: false`, and the second one has `global: true`.

Comment: You could remove the second `global:true` as the default is true.

Comment: It works for me. After I enabled the `pause on exceptions` option in chrome console, I found the `global` is `undefined`. This solution helped me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

add the following plugins in web.config.js file

```
 plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    {
      'apply': function(compiler) {
        compiler.parser.plugin('expression global', function() {
          this.state.module.addVariable('global', "(function() { return this; }()) || Function('return this')()");
          return true;
        });
      }
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

defined `webpackConfig` and add

```
plugins: [new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    global: {}
})],
```