# webpack with react.js aspnet - 'global' and 'exports' undefined

Tags: javascript, webpack, reactjs.net

I am trying to get a react application working with aspnet and I am using webpack.

This is my webpack config

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var pkg = require('./package.json');

// bundle dependencies in separate vendor bundle
var vendorPackages = Object.keys(pkg.dependencies).filter(function (el) {
return el.indexOf('font') === -1; // exclude font packages from vendor bundle
});

/*
 * Default webpack configuration for development
 */
var config = {
devtool: 'eval-source-map',
cache: true,
entry: {
    main: path.join(__dirname, "app", "App.js"),
    vendor: vendorPackages
},
output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "js"),
    filename: '[name].js',
    sourceMapFilename: "[file].map"
},

resolve: {
    modulesDirectories: ['node_modules'], alias: {}, extensions: ['', '.jsx', '.js']
},
plugins: [
    new webpack.OldWatchingPlugin(),  //needed to make watch work. see http://stackoverflow.com/a/29292578/1434764
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin(/* chunkName= */"vendor", /* filename= */"vendor.js")
],
resolveLoader: {
    'fallback': path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')
},
module: {
loaders: [{
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: 'babel',
    query: {
        presets: ['es2015','react']
    }
}, {
    test: /\.css$/,
    loader: 'style!css!'
}]
}
}

/*
 * If bundling for production, optimize output
 */
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
config.devtool = false;

config.plugins = [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),

    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        comments: false,
        compress: { warnings: false}
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production')}
    })
];
};

module.exports = config;
```

I am getting these 2 errors in the console when I try to access the page.

**SCRIPT5009: 'global' is undefined
vendor.js (42739,2)**

**SCRIPT5009: 'exports' is undefined
mobilelobbyapp.js (1,1)**

I can't figure out how to fix these. I did notice on a working example that the exported js file from webpack has

```
webpackJsonp([0],{
```

at the start of the file where mine has

```
exports.ids = [0];
exports.modules = {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this post ['global' undefined after running webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34856005/global-undefined-after-running-webpack) and I was able to fixSCRIPT5009: 'global' is undefined vendor.js by adding

new webpack.DefinePlugin({ global: {} }), to

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.OldWatchingPlugin(),  //needed to make watch work. see     https://stackoverflow.com/a/29292578/1434764
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin(/* chunkName= */"vendor", /* filename= */"vendor.js"),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({ global: {} }),
],
```

and then i fixed SCRIPT5009: 'exports' is undefined by removing

```
target: 'node',
```

from my webpack.config